# How to simplify multiple repeated if/else if statements in C programming

Tags: c, performance, if-statement, coordinates, coding-efficiency

I'm currently making a game that requires a lot if statements to figure out where the user clicks and to do things accordingly. It checks if the user clicks in the specified coordinates. The code below works perfectly fine, but I'm having trouble coming up with an efficient method to do this (not only for this code but any code in general).

```
if((mx > 78) && (mx < 113) && (my > 157) && (my < 191)) ifff(0, 0, 78, 157, 113, 191);
else if((mx > 116) && (mx < 150) && (my > 157) && (my < 191)) ifff(1, 0, 116, 157, 150, 191);
else if((mx > 153) && (mx < 188) && (my > 157) && (my < 191)) ifff(2, 0, 153, 157, 188, 191);
else if((mx > 196) && (mx < 230) && (my > 157) && (my < 191)) ifff(3, 0, 196, 157, 230, 191);
else if((mx > 233) && (mx < 267) && (my > 157) && (my < 191)) ifff(4, 0, 233, 157, 267, 191);
else if((mx > 270) && (mx < 303) && (my > 157) && (my < 191)) ifff(5, 0, 270, 157, 303, 191);
else if((mx > 311) && (mx < 345) && (my > 157) && (my < 191)) ifff(6, 0, 311, 157, 345, 191);
else if((mx > 348) && (mx < 384) && (my > 157) && (my < 191)) ifff(7, 0, 348, 157, 384, 191);
else if((mx > 388) && (mx < 421) && (my > 157) && (my < 191)) ifff(8, 0, 388, 157, 421, 191);

else if((mx > 78) && (mx < 113) && (my > 194) && (my < 229)) ifff(0, 1, 78, 194, 113, 229);
else if((mx > 116) && (mx < 150) && (my > 194) && (my < 229)) ifff(1, 1, 116, 194, 150, 229);
else if((mx > 153) && (mx < 188) && (my > 194) && (my < 229)) ifff(2, 1, 153, 194, 188, 229);
else if((mx > 196) && (mx < 230) && (my > 194) && (my < 229)) ifff(3, 1, 196, 194, 230, 229);
else if((mx > 233) && (mx < 267) && (my > 194) && (my < 229)) ifff(4, 1, 233, 194, 267, 229);
else if((mx > 270) && (mx < 303) && (my > 194) && (my < 229)) ifff(5, 1, 270, 194, 303, 229);
else if((mx > 311) && (mx < 345) && (my > 194) && (my < 229)) ifff(6, 1, 311, 194, 345, 229);
else if((mx > 348) && (mx < 384) && (my > 194) && (my < 229)) ifff(7, 1, 348, 194, 384, 229);
else if((mx > 388) && (mx < 421) && (my > 194) && (my < 229)) ifff(8, 1, 388, 194, 421, 229);

else if((mx > 78) && (mx < 113) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(0, 2, 78, 231, 113, 266);
else if((mx > 116) && (mx < 150) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(1, 2, 116, 231, 150, 266);
else if((mx > 153) && (mx < 188) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(2, 2, 153, 231, 188, 266);
else if((mx > 196) && (mx < 230) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(3, 2, 196, 231, 230, 266);
else if((mx > 233) && (mx < 267) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(4, 2, 233, 231, 267, 266);
else if((mx > 270) && (mx < 303) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(5, 2, 270, 231, 303, 266);
else if((mx > 311) && (mx < 345) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(6, 2, 311, 231, 345, 266);
else if((mx > 348) && (mx < 384) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(7, 2, 348, 231, 384, 266);
else if((mx > 388) && (mx < 421) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(8, 2, 388, 231, 421, 266);

else if((mx > 78) && (mx < 113) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(0, 3, 78, 231, 113, 266);
else if((mx > 116) && (mx < 150) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(1, 3, 116, 231, 150, 266);
else if((mx > 153) && (mx < 188) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(2, 3, 153, 231, 188, 266);
else if((mx > 196) && (mx < 230) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(3, 3, 196, 231, 230, 266);
else if((mx > 233) && (mx < 267) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(4, 3, 233, 231, 267, 266);
else if((mx > 270) && (mx < 303) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(5, 3, 270, 231, 303, 266);
else if((mx > 311) && (mx < 345) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(6, 3, 311, 231, 345, 266);
else if((mx > 348) && (mx < 384) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(7, 3, 348, 231, 384, 266);
else if((mx > 388) && (mx < 421) && (my > 231) && (my < 266)) ifff(8, 3, 388, 231, 421, 266);
```

Comment: Your fourth block of `else if` statements is suffering from copy'n'paste-itis.  It has the same y-range (`my > 231 && my < 266`) as the third block, so it is never any use because if the ranges match the third block takes precedence and if not, it just wastes time repeating a series of tests that will fail.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea is to find a way to represent the data in each of the lines/blocks in your code in some data structure and then create an array of those data structures and loop over them.

The simplest thing to do is create an array that will hold the data you want about each of these conditions.

For example,

```
[78, 113, 157, 191]   # represents first if statement
```

Then, you might create an array of 9 such arrays, that would represent the 9 conditions you have in each of the sections above.

Then, you might create an array of four such arrays, where each member would end up representing each of the sections in your code.

Finally, you just loop through all of them, like:

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    for (j=0; j<9; j++)
        if (mx > my_map[i][j][0]) && (mx < my_map[i][j][1]) ...
            ifff(j, i, my_map[i][j][0], ....
```

You can use structs instead of arrays, which will make the above easier to read, but I can't give an example since it's not clear from your code what the different sections are supposed to represent.

Answer (score 2):

For this there are data structures like the [interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), see the chapter from Cormen or some lectures from MIT course of algorithms about this data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be some structure in your intervals set. `((mx > 78) && (mx < 113))` is used several times... You may then reflect that structure in the code, like:

```
if ((mx > 78) && (mx < 113)
    if (condition on my)
    else if (condition on my)
    ...
else if (condition on mx)
    if (condition on my)
    else if (condition on my)
    ...
```

Of course, it will breaks the regularity of the reading, but everything has a price. You may even decompose more (idea is to test any condition once):

```
    if (mx > 78)
        if (mx < 113)
            if (first condition on my)
               if (second condition on my)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a comment, your fourth block of `else if` statements is suffering from copy'n'paste-itis.  It has the same y-range (`my > 231 && my < 266`) as the third block.  Consequently, it is never any use because if the ranges match, the third block takes precedence and if not, it just wastes time repeating a series of tests that will fail.

However, you have a fairly clear structure which can be far better represented by a couple of tables, a lookup function, and a single call to the `ifff()` function, like this:

```
struct Range
{
    int lo;
    int hi;
    int key;
};

static const struct Range x_range[] =
{
    {  78, 113, 0 },
    { 116, 150, 1 },
    { 153, 188, 2 },
    { 196, 230, 3 },
    { 233, 267, 4 },
    { 270, 303, 5 },
    { 311, 345, 6 },
    { 348, 384, 7 },
    { 388, 421, 8 },
};
enum { NUM_X_RANGE = sizeof(x_range) / sizeof(x_range[0]) };

static const struct Range y_range[] =
{
    { 157, 191, 0 },
    { 194, 229, 1 },
    { 231, 266, 2 },
    { 268, 299, 3 },    /* Guessed range */
};
enum { NUM_Y_RANGE = sizeof(y_range) / sizeof(y_range[0]) };

static inline int range_lookup(int val, const struct Range *range, int num_ranges)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_ranges; i++)
    {
        if (val > range[i].lo && val < range[i].hi)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

extern void ifff_range(int mx, int my);
extern void ifff(int xkey, int ykey, int xlo, int ylo, int xhi, int yhi);

void ifff_range(int mx, int my)
{
    int xr = range_lookup(mx, x_range, NUM_X_RANGE);
    int yr = range_lookup(my, y_range, NUM_Y_RANGE);
    if (xr != -1 && yr != -1)
        ifff(x_range[xr].key, y_range[yr].key,
             x_range[xr].lo,  y_range[yr].lo,
             x_range[xr].hi,  y_range[yr].hi);
}
```

In this data, the key values in the structure are identical to the index of the row in the array, so the key could be dropped from the structure.
There are numerous ways that the lookups can fail.  For example, `mx == 114` or `my == 192` would always fail.